No external access to my internal data after power failure
I have configured a Linux-Mint 21.3 Cinnamon computer so that I can access certain shared files via the Internet. The whole thing runs via a Fritzbox 7530AX and the external DNS service DNSHome. The shares on the Fritzbox are done via IPv6. Everything has worked perfectly so far.
Today, however, I had a power cut in the house and have not been able to access my files since.
I already checked some functions:

The Internet is working properly again.
The DNS service is queried by the Fritzbox.
Apache2 is also running perfectly.

What else should I check? Or does anyone have any suggestions as to what the problem might be?
I would appreciate it.
EDIT: It seems that it's finally working again. I switched the DNS first to IPv4 and then back to IPv6 and now everthing seems fine. No clue why.
Harry
